# Integrating Amazon SQS service into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, dependencies, amazon-sqs

I am trying to integrate Amazon SQS into eclipse but I'm having a hard time and I have no clue how to do that. I have watched many you tube videos and they all are with intelliJ or with visual studio code.
I tried with visual studio code but by default location is changing in the credentials.
Can anyone let me know the dependencies to add and how to create a project so that I can integrate AWS and also how to run the final application and how to make changes in the queue created?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you looking at writing a Java app that can invoke AWS Services using the AWS SDK for Java?

Comment: I am trying to add some data into SQS from the java application

Comment: See my answer below. Create a Maven project in Eclipse and add the POM in Git to your project's POM. Setup the dev environment as discussed in the 2nd link - including how to handle your creds. THen you can add the SQS code examples to your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the AWS SDK for Java V2 in Eclipse, all you need to do is create a Maven Project in Eclipse. Then look at the AWS SDK Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/sqs

See this illustration.

[image]

Open the POM located here and copy and paste it into your Maven project's POM file. That will add the required dependencies into your project. Now you can add the examples to your project to get SQS examples working in Eclipse.

Of course, you need to setup your development environment - which includes setting up your AWS credentials. To learn how to do this, see this topic:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)